# Display mean and median avoiding overlaping ggridges

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggridges

I'm working on a temperature data set over time and I used a density ridges plot to visualize my data by month. On each plot I included the median and the mean by using 2 `geom_density_ridges_gradient` function. The reason why I used two `geom_density_ridges_gradient`  function is because I wanted to distinguish them by two different colors. My issue is that the second layer/function (mean) is plotted on top of the first, causing an overlapping of the blue line (the mean) on others plot.

How can I avoing the overlapping ?

Here's the code below, I used  `lincoln_weather` dataset from `ggridges` as an example

```
library(ggridges)
library(ggplot2

ggplot(lincoln_weather, aes(x = `Mean Temperature [F]`, y = Month, fill = stat(x))) +
  geom_density_ridges_gradient(
    alpha = 0.8,
    color = "black",
    scale = 2,
    rel_min_height = 0,
    jittered_points = TRUE,
    position = position_points_jitter(
      width = 0.05,
      height = 0
    ),
    point_shape = "|",
    point_size = 3,
    point_alpha = 1,
    quantile_lines = TRUE,
    vline_color = c("green"),
    quantile_fun = median
  ) +
  geom_density_ridges_gradient(
    scale = 2,
    rel_min_height = 0,
    quantile_lines = TRUE,
    vline_color = c("blue"),
    fill = NA,
    quantile_fun = mean
  ) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(name = "Temp. [F]", option = "C") +
  labs(title = "Temperatures in Lincoln NE in 2016")
```

[image]

Comment: I know this is not the answer you're after, but just make two plots. I don't see a value in what you're trying to graph, not quite sure if it is possible, if I got your question right.

Comment: The problem is that i'm working on data set from different geographical locations. I already have a lot of plots and I dont want to have more plots to do just to fix another line.

Comment: I also want to keep that scale = 2 on`scale` argument. It makes the comparison easier between each month

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do what you want with two layers of ridges. I don't think there's a way to make a single layer do what you want either, as written. I actually think your best bet is to fork the ggridges package and edit the function so it let's you specify different colors for the mean line and the quantile line.

Comment: It would at least be a reasonable feature request for the package to expect/allow the `vline_color` arg to be the same length as the `quantile_fun` output.

Comment: Though perhaps you could work out something with `geom_segment` [as this issue is trying to do?](https://github.com/wilkelab/ggridges/issues/40)